# sqsd failing on Elastic Beanstalk worker with network/SSL issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, django, elastic-beanstalk

I have recently, simultaneously upgraded an Elastic Beanstalk worker application on several fronts; from Amazon Linux 1 to 2, Django 2.0 to 3.1, Python 3.6 to 3.7, Apache to Nginx, so there have been a lot of configuration changes.

The worker is using *sqsd* to poll a queue and it's generally running well since the upgrade, but I have suffered several incidents of the *sqsd* task stopping unexpectedly, and the Elastic Beanstalk instance being left dead in the water until it is manually restarted. After a previous incident, I reduced the number of workers to 3, on a 4 vCPU box, to try to ensure that contention wasn't causing a network time-out, but this problem has still recurred.

Googling the various messages in the `/var/log/aws-sqsd/default.log` haven't been particularly helpful.

As the log below starts, there are (days of) regular commands which worked fine, up until the problem occurred. The `SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A` errors, that precede *sqsd* failing, seem suggestive of an SSL configuration issue, but it seems unlikely that configuration issues like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814210/opensslsslsslerror-ssl-connect-syscall-returned-5-errno-0-state-sslv3-read/25819443) would suddenly affect a server after days of running smoothly.

```
2020-12-27T14:42:00Z message: sent to http://localhost:80/command/redacted 
2020-12-27T14:43:00Z message: sent to http://localhost:80/command/redacted
2020-12-27T14:45:00Z message: sent to http://localhost:80/command/redacted
2020-12-27T14:52:14Z message: sent to http://localhost:80/command/redacted
2020-12-27T15:02:59Z pollers: daemon exception during polling message from sqs: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
2020-12-27T15:03:56Z pollers: daemon exception during polling message from sqs: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
2020-12-27T15:05:17Z pollers: daemon exception during polling message from sqs: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
2020-12-27T15:05:17Z pollers: daemon exception during polling message from sqs: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
2020-12-27T15:05:27Z pollers: daemon exception during polling message from sqs: execution expired
2020-12-27T15:05:27Z pollers: daemon exception during polling message from sqs: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
2020-12-27T15:05:54Z pollers: daemon exception during polling message from sqs: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
2020-12-27T15:05:54Z pollers: daemon exception during polling message from sqs: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
2020-12-27T15:05:58Z pollers: daemon exception during polling message from sqs: Broken pipe - SSL_connect
2020-12-27T15:06:29Z pollers: daemon exception during polling message from sqs: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
2020-12-27T15:06:34Z pollers: daemon exception during polling message from sqs: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
2020-12-27T15:06:52Z pollers: daemon exception during polling message from sqs: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
2020-12-27T15:06:53Z pollers: daemon exception during polling message from sqs: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
2020-12-27T15:06:53Z pollers: daemon exception during polling message from sqs: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
2020-12-27T15:07:08Z pollers: daemon exception during polling message from sqs: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
2020-12-27T15:07:09Z pollers: daemon exception during polling message from sqs: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
2020-12-27T15:07:23Z pollers: daemon exception during polling message from sqs: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
2020-12-27T15:07:26Z pollers: daemon exception during polling message from sqs: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
#<Thread:0x0000563363a22910@/opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.3/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election/scheduler.rb:20 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:41:in `ssl_socket_connect': Net::OpenTimeout (Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError)
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:996:in `connect'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:930:in `do_start'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:925:in `start'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.6.0/delegate.rb:83:in `method_missing'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/connection_pool.rb:285:in `start_session'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/connection_pool.rb:92:in `session_for'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/handler.rb:119:in `session'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/handler.rb:71:in `transmit'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/handler.rb:45:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/content_length.rb:12:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/dynamodb_crc32_validation.rb:27:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/json/error_handler.rb:8:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/request_signer.rb:88:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/helpful_socket_errors.rb:10:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:108:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:139:in `retry_request'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:122:in `retry_if_possible'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:110:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:139:in `retry_request'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:122:in `retry_if_possible'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:110:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:139:in `retry_request'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:122:in `retry_if_possible'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:110:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:139:in `retry_request'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:122:in `retry_if_possible'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:110:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:139:in `retry_request'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:122:in `retry_if_possible'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:110:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/json/handler.rb:11:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/user_agent.rb:12:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/endpoint_pattern.rb:27:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/endpoint_discovery.rb:67:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/endpoint.rb:41:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_validator.rb:21:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:14:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/dynamodb_simple_attributes.rb:112:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/jsonvalue_converter.rb:20:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/idempotency_token.rb:18:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_converter.rb:20:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:21:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/seahorse/client/request.rb:70:in `send_request'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:207:in `block (2 levels) in define_operation_methods'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.3/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election/storage_manager.rb:315:in `heartbeat_record'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.3/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election/storage_manager.rb:310:in `counter_timestamp'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.3/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election/storage_manager.rb:289:in `register_as_worker'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.3/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election/daemon.rb:127:in `block (2 levels) in start'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.3/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election/daemon.rb:126:in `block in start'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.3/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election/scheduler.rb:27:in `block in start'
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:41:in `ssl_socket_connect': Net::OpenTimeout (Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError)
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:996:in `connect'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:930:in `do_start'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:925:in `start'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.6.0/delegate.rb:83:in `method_missing'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/connection_pool.rb:285:in `start_session'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/connection_pool.rb:92:in `session_for'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/handler.rb:119:in `session'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/handler.rb:71:in `transmit'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/handler.rb:45:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/content_length.rb:12:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/dynamodb_crc32_validation.rb:27:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/json/error_handler.rb:8:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/request_signer.rb:88:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/helpful_socket_errors.rb:10:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:108:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:139:in `retry_request'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:122:in `retry_if_possible'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:110:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:139:in `retry_request'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:122:in `retry_if_possible'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:110:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:139:in `retry_request'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:122:in `retry_if_possible'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:110:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:139:in `retry_request'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:122:in `retry_if_possible'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:110:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:139:in `retry_request'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:122:in `retry_if_possible'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:110:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/json/handler.rb:11:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/user_agent.rb:12:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/endpoint_pattern.rb:27:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/endpoint_discovery.rb:67:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/endpoint.rb:41:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_validator.rb:21:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:14:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/dynamodb_simple_attributes.rb:112:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/jsonvalue_converter.rb:20:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/idempotency_token.rb:18:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_converter.rb:20:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:21:in `call'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/seahorse/client/request.rb:70:in `send_request'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.546/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:207:in `block (2 levels) in define_operation_methods'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.3/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election/storage_manager.rb:315:in `heartbeat_record'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.3/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election/storage_manager.rb:310:in `counter_timestamp'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.3/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election/storage_manager.rb:289:in `register_as_worker'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.3/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election/daemon.rb:127:in `block (2 levels) in start'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.3/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election/daemon.rb:126:in `block in start'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.3/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election/scheduler.rb:27:in `block in start'
```

Comment: Not worthy of an answer as it might just be coincidence, but there is a possibility that it was running out of memory and the network issue was a consequence. A sizeable swap file was added to each instance and, since then, there has been no recurrence of the issue.